# jQuery selector for <select>'s <option> box

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML below, I need a jQuery selector that selects the `<option>` with the `with-stamp` class.

```
<select name="preset_select">
    <option selected="selected" value="original">ORIGINAL</option>
    <option value="large">LARGE</option>
    <option class="with-stamp" value="medium">MEDIUM</option>
</select>

$("select[name=preset_select]").change(function() {
    // console.log( $(this).hasClass("with-stamp") ); // all false
    // console.log( $("select[name=preset_select] option").hasClass("with-stamp") ); // all true
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$("select[name='preset_select']").change(function() {
    $(this).children(':selected').hasClass('with-timestamp')
}
```

Comment: Thank You, first I thought I didn't work but that I saw you changed my classname :-)

Comment: Ow sorry my bad.
Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to check only the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) `<option>` (since [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns `true` if *any* of the elements in the set have the class), like this:

```
$("select[name=preset_select] option:selected").hasClass("with-stamp")
```

Comment: I prefer PeeHaa's because it uses $(this)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("select[name=preset_select] option:selected").hasClass('with-stamp').change(function() { 

});
```

Comment: There's a `.class` selector, but besides that, the `change` event doesn't fire on the `<option>`, it fires on the `<select>`.